# JFrame loses focus after closing a JOptionPane and can't set it back

Tags: java, swing, focus, joptionpane

I have a `JOptionPane` that shows an input dialog with a `JTextField`. When this dialog is closed, it returns the text inserted.

But when any button (Confirm/Cancel) is pressed and the dialog is closed, the main window loses focus and I'm unable to set on it again.

```
String menuName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
    new JFrame(), 
    "Insert new Menu Name"
);
```

How can I set focus on the main window when this dialog closes?

Comment: Wait a second... I didn't spot it at first but from the revisions it seems you used a previous question and re-edited it completely to ask a new question... That is not how things are done. For a new question you should ask a new question. Not edit a completely different one! Don't do that again please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the parent component as the first parameter, not some random new frame you created.

Supposing you are launching this from within a JFrame method, you can run

```
String menuName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
    this, // parent component is the JFrame you are launching this from
    "Insert new Menu Name"
);
```

In some cases, eg when running this from an `onLostFocus` implementation of a `FocusListener` you need to run this after all current events have been handled. This can be done by posting an event at the end of the event queue. Use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to do that.

So if you are in such a situation, launch the dialog as follows. Suppose the frame class you are running this from is called `MyFrame`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String menuName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog (
            MyFrame.this, // parent component is the JFrame you are launching this from
            "Insert new Menu Name"
        );
        // do stuff with menuName
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)